# Angular slickgrid dynamic editor collection by every row data

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

This is my slickgrid dataset

```
[{title : 'foo', prerequisites : true}, {title : 'bar', prerequisites : false}]
```

These are my column definitions:

```
[
     {
        id: "title",
        name: "Title", 
        field: "title"
     },  
     {
        id: 'prerequisites', name: 'Prerequisites', field: 'prerequisites',
        type: FieldType.string,
        editor: {
          model: Editors.multipleSelect,
          collection: [{ value: '', label: '' }, { value: true, label: 'true' }, { value: false, label: 'false' }]
        }
      }]
```

This creates a static editor dropdown for every row in the prerequisites column.

But what I want is to have, that the dropdown **doesn't have the true option** in the row where the title is **foo**

*In other words*, I want to hide some options in case of some selected rows, based on another column's value in the corresponding row.

Comment: Sadly you can't do that with current version, I mean you can filter the `collection` as shown in this [Wiki](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Select-Filter#collection-filterbysortby) but that is the entire collection of every row on a Filter/Editor and is cannot be changed dynamically. The only 2 options you have would be to 1) create a Custom Editor (maybe extend current select editor) or 2) contribute to the library... note that I'm the author of Angular-Slickgrid

Comment: There is now a new option to do that in the latest version `2.25.0` of Angular-Slickgrid via `collectionOverride`, see the updated answer below. You can also upvote the answer and the lib ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

With the latest version `2.25.0` of Angular-Slickgrid (see [here](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v2.25.0)), we now have an option to override the collection right from the column definitions as asked in the original question. There's also a new [Wiki - Collection Override](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/wiki/Select-Dropdown-Editor-(single,multiple)#collection-override)

For example you can now do this

```js
this.columnDefinitions = [
  {
    id: 'prerequisites', name: 'Prerequisites', field: 'prerequisites',
    type: FieldType.string,
    editor: {
      model: Editors.multipleSelect,
      collection: [{ value: '', label: '' }, { value: true, label: 'true' }, { value: false, label: 'false' }]
        },
      collectionOverride: (finalCollection, args) => {
        console.log(args); 
        if (args.dataContext.title === 'foo') {
          return finalCollection.filter((col) => col.value !== true);
        }
        return finalCollection;
      },
    }
  }
];
```

Also note that all the Editors, Filters and Formatters are now Public so that it's easier to `extend` from, e.g. `export class CustomSelectEditor extends SelectEditor`

---

Original Answer
Select Editor/Filter was never built with dynamic collection and access to the item dataContext in mind but similar to the other SO [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65419643/1212166) I gave to your other SO Question, you can again extend the Select Editor and override the [filterCollection()](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L484) function, which is called just before `renderDomElement()` and that is the best place to override the output collection before it is passed to the `renderDomElement(inputCollection)` function

Note that I did not test the code below but I expect the concept to work, I'm not sure if `SelectEditor` is actually public, if it's not then try to extend `Editors.singleSelect` and `Editors.multipleSelect`

Try first to extend `SelectEditor` directly (I think they are not currently public and that won't work, but I'll probably change that in future version)

```js
import { SelectEditor } from 'angular-slickgrid';

export class CustomSelectEditor extends SelectEditor {
  constructor(protected args: EditorArguments, protected isMultipleSelect) {
    super(args, true);
  }

  protected filterCollection(): any[] {
    const activeCell: { row: number; cell: number; } = this.grid.getActiveCell();
    const dataContext = this.grid.getDataItem(activeCell.row);
    // your custom logic
    // const customCollection = ...
    return customCollection;
  }
}
```

or `Editors.singleSelect` if `SelectEditor` is not publicly available and if that is the way to go, then you'll also have to extend `Editors.multipleSelect` OR create 1 Custom Editor and pass `true` for multiple or `false` for single in the `super(args, true)` call

```js
import { Editors } from 'angular-slickgrid';

export class CustomSelectEditor extends Editors.inputText {
  constructor(protected args: EditorArguments, protected isMultipleSelect) {
    super(args, true);
  }

  protected filterCollection(): any[] {
    const activeCell: { row: number; cell: number; } = this.grid.getActiveCell();
    const dataContext = this.grid.getDataItem(activeCell.row);
    // your custom logic
    // const customCollection = ...
    return customCollection;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this worked for me. I just extended *Editors.multipleSelect*. Also I took parameter *inputCollection* in the" filterCollection" method and manipulated it

Answer (score 0):

Your 'multipleSelect' editor has an `Init` event. This is where you should select the values for the select list.

The editor is instantiated from the grid with a lot of info in the `args` var in the constructor. Here is the grid code to instantiate the editor:

```
  currentEditor = new useEditor({
    grid: self,
    gridPosition: absBox($container[0]),
    position: absBox(activeCellNode),
    container: activeCellNode,
    column: columnDef,
    columnMetaData: columnMetaData,
    item: item || {},
    event: e,
    commitChanges: commitEditAndSetFocus,
    cancelChanges: cancelEditAndSetFocus
  });
```

Your `init` event can test the current row of the grid (`args.item`) and provide row values for the editor lookup.

Comment: what is useEditor?

Comment: Also, I need to have all functionalities of 'multipleSelect' and want to just add this feature. Is that possible somehow?

Comment: The code shown above is internal to ```slickgrid.js``` - I just wanted to show the ```args``` object that gets passed to the editor constructor. I am assuming you have already got a multipleSelect editor working. The changes will need to be made to that editor. Perhaps you could add the editor code to your question.