# Angular slickgrid edit handler does not trigger on selecting same value from dropdown

Tags: slickgrid, angular-slickgrid

I have a requirement in angular slickgrid where I want to edit the row with the same option which in result will update the date on which the update was made.

What I actually do is call an API on edit command handler when any changes are made in the table, but when I click on the same option from dropdown, the handler is not triggered(which is valid as there was no change made, but for my purpose I need that to be triggered)

So my code looks something like this:

These are my grid options

```
{
            enableAutoResize: true,
            enableSorting: true,
            editable: true,
            autoEdit: true,
            autoCommitEdit: true,
            editCommandHandler : (item, column, editCommand) => EditHandler(item, column, editCommand)//This is my EditHandler method which gets triggered and calls an API in backend
}
```

This is my column definition

```
{
    id: 'status', name: 'Status', field: 'status', 
    filterable: true,
    editor: {
      collection: [{ value: 'progress', label: 'Progress' }, { value: 'new', label: 'New' }, { value: 'done', label: 'Done' }],
      model: Editors.singleSelect
    }
  }
```

Now suppose If a row contains *Progress* in the status column and when I change that to *New* from dropdown my *EditHandler* method triggers and I proceed with my changes.

But what I want is to **click on Progress again** and want to trigger the **EditHandler** method and call the API which updates the date with the same status

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT

The following works and I tested it. I also added code to keep the last event name triggered (onClose/onOpen) so that you won't trigger the editCommandHandler when opening the select dropdown. You should also use the latest version of Angular-Slickgrid version `2.25.0`, all the Editors/Filters are now Public so it's easier to extend them (see latest [Release Note](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/releases/tag/v2.25.0)).

```js
export class CustomSelectEditor extends SingleSelectEditor {
  private lastEventName = '';

  constructor(args) {
    super(args);

    // retrieve the options that were provided to multipleSelect.JS
    // we will override the onClose/onOpen to get last event name triggered
    // Note: make sure that the onClose is still calling the this.save() else nothing will work
    const libOptions = this.editorDomElement.multipleSelect('getOptions');
    libOptions.onClose = () => {
      this.lastEventName = 'onClose';
      this.save();
    };
    libOptions.onOpen = () => {
      this.lastEventName = 'onOpen';
    }
    this.editorDomElement.multipleSelect('refreshOptions', libOptions);
  }

  isValueChanged(): boolean {
    // return true only when it's the onClose event to fire the editCommandHandler
    if (this.lastEventName === 'onClose') {
      return true;
    }

    // but keep previous logic when it's not the onClose event
    if (this.isMultipleSelect) {
      return !charArraysEqual(this.$editorElm.val(), this.originalValue);
    }
    return this.$editorElm.val() !== this.originalValue;
  }
}
```

---

All Editors were written in a way to avoid triggering events when nothing changed, if you really wish to change that behavior then you could extend the `SelectEditor` and override the [isValueChanged()](https://github.com/ghiscoding/Angular-Slickgrid/blob/master/src/app/modules/angular-slickgrid/editors/selectEditor.ts#L444) function.

Note that I did not test the code below but it should work, I'm not sure if `SelectEditor` is actually public, if it's not then try to extend `Editors.singleSelect` and `Editors.multipleSelect`

Try first to extend `SelectEditor` directly (I think they are not currently public and that won't work, but I'll probably change that in future version)

```js
import { SelectEditor } from 'angular-slickgrid';

export class CustomSelectEditor extends SelectEditor {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  isValueChanged(): boolean {
    // your custom logic
  }
}
```

or `Editors.singleSelect` if `SelectEditor` is not publicly available

```js
import { Editors } from 'angular-slickgrid';

export class CustomSelectEditor extends Editors.inputText {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  isValueChanged(): boolean {
    // your custom logic
  }
}
```

then use it in your custom editor in your column definitions

```js
{
    id: 'status', name: 'Status', field: 'status', 
    filterable: true,
    editor: {
      collection: [{ value: 'progress', label: 'Progress' }, { value: 'new', label: 'New' }, { value: 'done', label: 'Done' }],
      model: CustomSelectEditor 
    }
}
```

Comment: It behaves in a strange manner. I just returned *true* in the *isValueChanged* method and the edit handler triggered just on the click of the editor (before changing any value)

Comment: I updated the answer (on top), the code I provided works, I tested it